# In finishing an jQuery-ajax-PHP tutorial, why is it broken?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm running through a tutorial that is a little dated, but I've tried to improve the code and make it up-to-date.

The code is well commented and easy to follow, but I saw use of things like the `<b>` tag, which I think it deprecated, making me think it was a bit old....  And I also wonder, why is `DB.php` included, when there's a connect command, already, in the php file?

Please, have a look at the code and tell me why it isn't working?

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phpmysql.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1) Create some html content that can be accessed by jquery
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------>
  <h2> Bookstore example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output">Will you look at some books?</div>
  <button>click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the js:

```
$(document).ready.(
  function () 
  {
    $("button").click.(function()
    {
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------
      // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------
      $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'form3.php',   //the script to call to get data          
        data: "",       //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                        //for example "id=5&parent=6"
        dataType: 'json',                //data format      
        success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
        {
          var id = data[0];              //get id
          var vname = data[1];           //get name
          //------------------------------------------------------------------
          // 3) Update html content
          //------------------------------------------------------------------
          $('#output').html("<p>Title: </p>"+id+"<p> Content: </p>"+vname); //Set output element html
        } 
      });
    }); 
  });
```

And the php:

```
<?php 

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "username";
  $pass = "password";

  $databaseName = "auto_try";
  $tableName = "books";

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");      //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                      //fetch result    

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Which development environment are you working on? LAMP or WAMP? Have you checked the PHP error logs and the Firebug console for errors?

Comment: Could be a number of issues. Open up your browser inspector to see if the request is even being made when you click the button. Star there, then debug your PHP script. Do you have a working MySQL db on that machine, and is it running @ localhost? You also have a few syntax errors.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Yeah, the request is being made.  MySQL works.  I can perform the action with simple php forms.

Comment: @air4x the problem is what the answerer identified as the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your js jquery function was wrong try this,there is no `.` after ready or click

```
 $(document).ready(
      function () 
      {
        $("button").click(function()
        {.....
```

Comment: Fixed that.  Still doesn't work. :'(  Actually, I can't find any working scripts like this on the Net.

Comment: now the xhr request is working check your server side code.

Comment: ArunKillu You mean this actually works for you?  Can you post the full code?  I've reversioned and editted the question several times and don't know which code you are using.  I can look at the changes based on a full version?

Comment: I found some working scripts that are similar.  It took about 3 weeks, total.  There's a lot of good code at jensbits' jquery section.